# escape sequence for & in C#.net

Tags: c#

I am retrieving data from database using C#.net win. app.
The table contains values as `&` and `&&` . but when these values are displayed on win. forms in labels for first `&` - the label is blank.
for 2nd `&&` - label displays single `&`.

Please tell me what escape sequence i should add in access db so that `&` is displayed in label1 and `&&` is displayed in label 2.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please look for entities and why it must be encoded (it's a part of the spec). So you must convert `&` to `&amp;`

Comment: It seems you are answering your own question. & is the escape character for & i.e. replace all occurrences of & by &&.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `UseMnemonic` property ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.usemnemonic)) to `false` on your `Labels`